# Accessing global variable give junk values

Tags: c, x86, global

I was trying to print variables through UART with following code in C.

Processor - Intel 80486

Compiler - IC compiler (from Intel, released in 1990)

```
uint32_t unGlobal = 0xABCDEF90;

void main (void)
{
    uint32_t unLocal = 0x12345678;

    UartWrite (unLocal);
    UartWrite (unGlobal);
}
```

UartWrite() is the serial port driver. UartWrite's argument is 32 bit and internally it prints each character.

Here, **local variable is printed correctly, but printing global variable gives junk values!** What could be the reason for not getting the value of the global variable.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: did you try it with other values? If you switch the values of the global and local variable, does it change the behaviour?

Comment: What happens if you swap the write lines around and print the global first?  Whart happens if you chage over the values so that the global is 0x12345678?

Comment: Come on - do some debugging.  Try stuff, see what happens, instead of pointlessly posting two lines to SO:((

Comment: what is the junk value? is it always the same?

Comment: Swapping order, changing values does not change the behavior.The global is still not printed correctly.

Comment: You might shed some light on the problem by looking at the assembly code.

Comment: @mch, I assigned the global to local and then printed. It gives the same junk value as the global.

Comment: A qualified guess would be that the compiler is crappy, pre-standard junk, which doesn't perform initialization of static storage variables correctly. Try `uint32_t unGlobal;` then in main `unGlobal = 0xABCDEF90;   UartWrite (unGlobal);`. If that solved the problem, go check for compiler options related to static initialization, "ANSI startup" or whatever they may be called.

Comment: @Lundin - _crappy, pre-standard junk_ and _qualified guess_, funny, but mutually exclusive statements I think.  BTW, I found some documentation that suggests `static` declared globals have an attribute of HIDDEN, which makes variable hidden _to other components_ in some of the old intel compilers.  Not sure what that means exactly, but probably related.   The doc (released in 1990, and referenced below) has a lot of content on this topic.

Comment: @ryyker My knee jerk reaction is that the problem is related to static initialization. I'm used to embedded systems, where it is incredibly common to have a non-standard initialization procedure of static storage duration variables. It wouldn't surprise me if this was also the case for PC:s back in the days.

Comment: @ryyker and Lundin, you were right. The problem is with static initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with static initialization. Because re-initializing the global variable at run-time gives correct value.
Thanks  ryyker, @Lundin and all

Answer (score 1):

The argument ***[type](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm)*** in the prototype for UartWrite may not be sufficient size to contain the value for your global.  I do not have the prototype, but for ***[similar](http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/uart_library.htm#uartx_write_gen)*** functions (different libraries no doubt), the argument type is `char`.   If it is also `char` in your prototype, then passing a value for `unsigned int` would be the likely source of your problem.

The following illustrates the scenario where a function will accept a variable of size too large for the prototype without error, but then can produce unexpected results:

```
int func(char a)
{
    a = 10000;
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10000;
    int b;
    b = func(a);// note int type, or 10000 does not fit into a char type
                // b is returned, but not with the expected value.
    printf("%d" b);
    return 0;
}
```

***results:  b = -24***

Post the prototype for `UartWrite (??? )`;

***EDIT*** (new information)

I found ***[this Intel document on a compiler released in 1990](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEgQFjAGahUKEwjAoaSEjabHAhWGXZIKHU2-AKY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.physics.udel.edu%2F~bnikolic%2FQTTG%2Fshared%2Fdocs%2Fintel_c_user_and_reference_guide.pdf&ei=KZPMVYDpMoa7yQTN_IKwCg&usg=AFQjCNFuLZRrKnwAMpW_47PIPhG9JNygxA&sig2=e-rdQhMfUdTLlC-_rd52zA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.aWw&cad=rja)*** that may be a cousin to the compiler you are using. Look at sections starting on page 68:

> Each global symbol definition or reference in a compilation unit has a
>   visibility attribute that controls how (or if) it may be referenced
>   from outside the component in which it is defined. There are five
>   possible values for visibility:
>     • EXTERNAL – The compiler must treat
>   the symbol as though it is defined in another component. For a
>   definition, this means that the compiler must assume that the symbol
>   will be overridden (preempted) by a definition of the same name in
>   another component. See Symbol Preemption. If a function 69 symbol has 
>   external visibility,
>   the compiler knows that it must be called indirectly and can inline
>   the indirect call stub.
>     • DEFAULT – Other components can reference the
>   symbol. Furthermore, the symbol definition may be overridden
>   (preempted) by a definition of the same name in another component.
>     • PROTECTED – Other components can reference the symbol, but it cannot
>   be preempted by a definition of the same name in another component.
>     • HIDDEN – Other components cannot directly reference the symbol.
>   However, its address might be passed to other components indirectly
>   (for example, as an argument to a call to a function in another
>   component, or by having its address stored in a data item reference by
>   a function in another component).
>     • INTERNAL – The symbol cannot be
>   referenced outside its defining component, either directly or
>   indirectly.

***A little further down*** For example:

```
int i __attribute__ ((visibility("default")));
void __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) x () {...}
extern void y() __attribute__ ((visibilty("protected");
```

There is much more there.  Hope this helps.

Comment: void UartWrite (uint32_t)

Comment: @Anantha - Well, with that I am perplexed.  Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with _IC compiler_, and I know nothing of the implementation of `UartWrite()`.  Clearly, variable size alone is not a contributor to the issue as a `uint32_t`  should handle a value up to ***4,294,967,295***, while your global (the larger of the two values in your post) in decimal form in equal to a little over half that value (***2882400144***).  I hope you will post the solution when you discover it.

Comment: UartWrite() uses char write function to print each byte.  IC compiler is very old, may be before C90 std.  Could the issue be related to x486 segmentation or local in stack and global in data segment or some kind?

Comment: @Anantha - Not likely that a 32 bit int would cause a problem related to the i486 Segmentation issues.  However.  I have written code for Rabbit uPs, and there was a special way to initialize global variables that might be in some way similar to what you would have to do in your environment.   See my edit above for details.  (too detailed for a comment)

Comment: The issue is that the initial values are not included while building. When I reinitialize the global at run time, it is printed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

C keyword **volatile** indicates "that a value may change between different accesses, even if it does not appear to be modified". Try this and see if this works for you.

Comment: ***[volitile](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#volatile)***  ***OP did not use this keyword*** in the post, so it is unlikely that the values of the declared variables would have been changed by another process.  If it had been used, this (your answer) would have been a likely scenario as values are every reference to the variable will reload the contents from memory, and not from a registry somewhere.

Comment: Hi rykker. What I mean is that he should add this modifier. In case it is not used then the compiler might optimize the usage of this variable and therefore may give unexpected values.

Comment: Yes, I understood that.  But would that have really solved the problem?  There are unknowns OP has not provided, such as what size (type) is the argument of _UartWrite(?)_  If it is `char`, passing an `uint` will be a problem.

Comment: UartWrite's argument is 32 bit and internally it prints each character. No other process/ function is accessing the global variable and it is not modified outside the program.